# Kubernetes preStop hook

Tags: kubernetes

I think kubernetes preStop hook capabilities are poorly defined.

my requirement is straight forward to call an API to identify if pod crashed but I am not getting any logs even though I have added `echo` statment in the `command` section

Can someone point me to example that achieve similar requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The preStop hook is designed for orderly shutdown, not for crash notifications. (kubelet will restart the container automatically for you anyway)

Comment: But what if we have restart policy set to Never and all we want is something like kill the child process and then notify about it.

Comment: You can use the kubernetes api and build a notification application